# Android hotspot have high ping response time

Tags: android, ping, latency, tethering

I made Android hotspot from Settings and I tried to connect various devices on it : Laptop, iPhone (Maximum 1 device was on the hotspot)
and when I wanted to ping connected device from Android device, ping response time was very high in situation when waiting period between pings is higher then a few seconds. But when I pinged connected device without waiting time, ping response time was lower, which is good.

Example :

hotspot : LG G4, Android OS 6.0 or Nexus 5 , Android OS 6.0

connected device : Macbook Pro or iPhone.

When I run this command  : **ping 192.168.43.143** in adb shell
I am getting this result :

64 bytes from 192.168.43.143: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=**32.9 ms**

64 bytes from 192.168.43.143: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=**9.57 ms**

64 bytes from 192.168.43.143: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=**15.4 ms**

64 bytes from 192.168.43.143: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=**12.4 ms**

64 bytes from 192.168.43.143: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=**10.9 ms**

64 bytes from 192.168.43.143: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=**10.3 ms**

64 bytes from 192.168.43.143: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=**16.8 ms**

64 bytes from 192.168.43.143: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=**12.7 ms**

64 bytes from 192.168.43.143: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=**11.1 ms**

64 bytes from 192.168.43.143: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=**17.7 ms**

64 bytes from 192.168.43.143: icmp_seq=11 ttl=64 time=**11.8 ms**

When I run this command  : **ping -i 10 192.168.43.143** in adb shell
I am getting this result :

64 bytes from 192.168.43.143: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=**37.4 ms**

64 bytes from 192.168.43.143: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=**49.3 ms**

64 bytes from 192.168.43.143: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=**185 ms**

64 bytes from 192.168.43.143: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=**108 ms**

64 bytes from 192.168.43.143: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=**134 ms**

64 bytes from 192.168.43.143: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=**165 ms**

64 bytes from 192.168.43.143: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=**193 ms**

64 bytes from 192.168.43.143: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=**30.6 ms**

64 bytes from 192.168.43.143: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=**49.8 ms**

64 bytes from 192.168.43.143: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=**84.7 ms**

64 bytes from 192.168.43.143: icmp_seq=11 ttl=64 time=**112 ms**

Conclusion : When waiting period is 10 seconds, ping response time is much higher.

This is a problem for me because I want to have REST WebService on connected device and I want to have high response time.

If someone have some idea or solution it would be very helpful for me because I am not sure what is going on here :)

Thanks.

Comment: This might explain what’s going on. http://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/efficient-network-access.html

Comment: Hello Jasse, Thank for the quick response. Probably I wasn't clear in my post, but in my case 3g (Data) is not the problem because I don't use it at all. It's a just communication over Wifi when Android is hotspot and other device is connected on hotspot with pinging over wlan0 network interface. In some cases I even turned AirPlane mode on, and results were same :(